# PostgresSQL with psycopg2 connection issues when idle for hour

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am connecting to connect PostgreSQL using psycopg2 initially it's working. But when I am using same connection after an hour it's throwing the connection error
         `"psycopg2.OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request."`

PostgreSQL version-  12.3
Kindly Let me know should I need to pass any additional params to connectin string or need to any change configuration in PostgreSQL?

The following program  I am using

```
import psycopg2
import time
try:
    con = psycopg2.connect(user = "test",password = "*******",
                                              host = "localhost",
                                              port = "5432",
                                              database = "test")
    if(con):
        print("Connection  created successfully")
    while True:
            ps_cursor = con.cursor()
            ps_cursor.execute("select * from users limit 1")
            mobile_records = ps_cursor.fetchone()
            for row in mobile_records:
                print (row)
            #Use this method to release the connection object and send back to connection pool
            time.sleep(3600) 

except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error :
    print ("Error while connecting to PostgreSQL", error)
```

Comment: You need to check PostgreSQL log file: there should be a message explaining why the session has been terminated.

Comment: Also check your `postgresql.conf` to see if `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` is set to some non-zero value.
You will know this is the problem if the postgres logs say `FATAL:  terminating connection due to idle-in-transaction timeout`.
See this: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-IDLE-IN-TRANSACTION-SESSION-TIMEOUT

Comment: Thank you Pifor and James ..

Comment: Why are you doing this in the first place? Holding a connection open for an hour to run one query seems to be excessive.